# NEP-141 implementation

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

While trying to implement NEP-141 fungible token, I am using [trait](https://github.com/amiyatulu/NEP-141-FT/blob/main/src/core.rs)

```
impl FungibleTokenCore for FungibleToken {

fn ft_transfer(&mut self, receiver_id: ValidAccountId, amount: U128, memo: Option<String>) {
        assert_one_yocto();
        let sender_id = env::predecessor_account_id();
        let amount: Balance = amount.into();
        self.internal_transfer(&sender_id, receiver_id.as_ref(), amount, memo);
    }

}
```

But the problem is the function ft_transfer is inaccessible from the contract. It gives error:
"Contract method is not found".

```
export TOKEN=dev-1618119753426-1904392
near call $TOKEN ft_transfer '{"receiver_id":"avrit.testnet", "amount": 10, "memo":""}' --accountId=amiyatulu.testnet
```

Comment: I have no experience with near, I do not know how it works. However, I'll venture to guess that you need to add an [`extern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.extern.html) function, so it can call it.

Answer (score 3):

Your method must be public.  See the `near-sdk-rs` docs README for a few examples.

https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs

Comment: No, got the error, its because I have not added #[near_bindgen] macro

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a `pub` before that `fn`. See [Best Practices](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/master/HELP.md#public-vs-private-methods).

Also see [FT example](https://github.com/near-examples/FT/blob/master/ft/src/lib.rs). You can use the [near-contract-standards](https://crates.io/crates/near-contract-standards) library to simplify your efforts.

Comment: I am unable to add custom logic into the token using the library, so not using it.

Comment: What sort of custom logic are you trying to add, @AmiyaBehera?

Comment: Like burning some tokens during transfer.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in a comment, the problem is that you need to:

- Use `#[near_bindgen]` for the impl definition:

```rust
#[near_bindgen]
impl FungibleTokenCore for FungibleToken { ... }
```

- Use a public method:

```rust
pub fn ft_transfer(&mut self, ...)
```

There is already an implementation of this token in [near-contract-standards](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/tree/master/near-contract-standards/src/fungible_token)

> I am unable to add custom logic into the token using the library, so not using it.

Regarding how to extend the behaviour of the toke I suggest you to take a look at how the Rainbow Bridge does it for ERC20 tokens bridged to Near: [BridgeToken](https://github.com/aurora-is-near/rainbow-token-connector/blob/master/bridge-token/src/lib.rs#L23-L32). We also needed to extend its functionalities, and for this end, we used the Token as an internal field, and then changed a bit the public functions exposed.

There is also [a useful macro](https://github.com/aurora-is-near/rainbow-token-connector/blob/master/bridge-token/src/lib.rs#L116-L117) to derive base implementation for common functions.

> Like burning some tokens during transfer.

To this, you can follow the previous approach, without using the macro to expose all functions, and instead implement `ft_transfer` properly for your use case, but still making calls to the inner field: `token: FungibleToken`.